# Java recursion question

Tags: java, recursion, short-circuiting

Here's a section of code from one of my classes:

```
public void run() {  

    SomeClass[][] someClassArray = new SomeClass[6][];  
    someClassArray[0] = new SomeClass[1];  
    someClassArray[1] = new SomeClass[4];  
    someClassArray[2] = new SomeClass[16];  
    someClassArray[3] = new SomeClass[64];  
    someClassArray[4] = new SomeClass[256];  
    someClassArray[5] = new SomeClass[1024];

    someFunction(0,0); 
}

someFunction(int i, int j) {  
    if(i == 5) {  
        someClassArray[i][j].flag = test(i,j); // BASE CASE  
    }  
    else {  
        if(someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4))  
                && someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+1))  
                && someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+2))  
                && someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+3)))  
            someClassArray[i][j].flag = true;  
        else  
            someClassArray[i][j].flag = false;  
    }  

    return someClassArray[i][j].flag;
}


class SomeClass {  

        boolean flag;  
        // other stuff  
}  

boolean test(int i, int j) {  

        // test some property of this coordinate  
}
```

Essentially what I want is to set the flag of one SomeClass object to true only if the four corresponding objects' flags in the next array level are also true. Unfortunately, I seem to be having problems with this:

```
if(someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4))  
&& someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+1))  
&& someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+2))  
&& someFunction(someClassArray(i+1,j*4+3)))
```

It looks like it's only checking the first condition (I added in a counter so check how many times someFunction is called and it only went up to 6, rather than the 1365 I should be getting); are you not able to do multiple function calls in an if statement in Java? or am I doing it wrong?

(Sorry about the formatting by the way; this is my first time posting here)

Comment: Welcome to the best programming-related forum on the web :)

Comment: someFunction(someClassArray[i+1][j*4]) doesn't match the function signature

Comment: Oops, messed that up when I was copying; it should be right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operands `&&` and `||` are so called [short-circuiting operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuiting_operator). This means the logic they are in will immediately stop executing if the result in known.

In your case, it probably means that the result of the first call to `SomeFunction` is `false`. Because you only have AND on that line, the result can't possibly be `true` anymore and thus your other 3 calls to `SomeFunction` don't get executed.

Bottom-line: change the `&&` to `&`, this won't short-circuit and all call will get executed.

Comment: @bendicott If you like the answer, please upvote & accept it, thanks!

Comment: However, the short-circuiting does in fact work correctly, and usually shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If condition can be short-circuited if its outcome is clear from the first function call.

Comment: Said this way looks like it's a property of `if`, while indeed it's a property of `&&`

Comment: @ what's his name: it's also a property of ||.